# Get Customer Details by Wishlist Product Id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

A list of products was added to wishlist by the number of customers and i need to know that which customer was added a particular product to the wishlist, based on the product id.

How to get the customer details or atleast a customer id based on the product id?

Comment: It works...[https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Get-Customer-Details-by-Wishlist-Product-Id/m-p/117440/highlight/false#M6756]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worked code for me as below:

First iam getting the collection from the wishlist_item table and filter with my product id.

```
$wishlistItemCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('product_id', ['eq' => $productId]);
```

Then joined the wishlist_item and wishlist table using the common field name wishlist_id and gets the customer_id into the wishlistItemCollection

```
$joinConditions = 'main_table.wishlist_id = wishlist.wishlist_id';
    $wishlistItemCollection->getSelect('*')->join(
             ['wishlist'],
             $joinConditions,
             []
            )->columns("wishlist.customer_id");
```

Using the customer_id we can get all the customer details as below:

```
    foreach($wishlistItemCollection as $wishlistData){
        $customerId = $wishlistData->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->load($customerId);
        $customerData = $customer->getData();
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname();
        $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
    }
```